# Create an user role for order status validation on WooCommerce

Tags: php, plugins, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I need a role with same privileges as customer, but with the addition of being able to change the order status from "awaiting payment" to "paid" (or any other status names). Also, with the privilege of deleting orders with "awaiting payment" status.

This role should not have privileges to change the order status back from "paid" to "awaiting payment" or to delete orders with "paid" status or any other privilege.

I tried some plugins as User Role Editor, but doesn't grant access to the Order Status Manager. Does anyone know how to do this using plugins or php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to accomplish this by the combination of several solutions:

1. Using the Advanced Access Manager plugin, I created an user with the capabilities: read, edit posts, manage woocommerce and edit shop orders. As this capabilities enabled many admin menu options I didn't want this role to have, I restricted access to all backend menu except for "Orders" in the woocommerce menu.
2. However, there were options in the admin menu that couldn't be restricted by the plugin, so I used the recommendation at

> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/136058/how-to-remove-admin-menu-pages-inserted-by-plugins

and

> https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/142517/remove-ability-to-access-certain-admin-menus

to add the next code to functions.php:

> ```
> add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );
> function my_remove_menu_pages() {
>   if(isset(wp_get_current_user()->roles[0]) && wp_get_current_user()->roles[0] == 'financieros'){ 
>       remove_menu_page('edit.php?post_type=uncodeblock'); 
>       remove_menu_page('wpcf7');  
>       remove_menu_page('heypublisher-submission-manager'); } }
> ```